# Application Referencing Incorrect Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: oracle, dll, gac

An application is attempting to reference Oracle.DataAccess v4.112.2.0:

[image]

..but I have v4.112.3.0 in the GAC (installed from the Oracle client setup.exe file for 11.2.0.3).

[image]

I have no control of the source code, how could I find and download Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.2.0 to register in the GAC?

Thanks!

Update:  After downloading the ODAC x64 from the link provided by __, I'm now receiving the following error:
[image]

I assume I can't have multiple Oracle.DataAccess dlls registered in the GAC?  Any input?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.2.0 comes with the 11.2.0.2 Oracle Client.

You can download the full Oracle Client with the installer from http://support.oracle.com (patch number 10098816, zip 4of7). You need a valid support subscription on your customer support identifier to do this, but this shouldnt be a problem, since you have already managed to get the 11.2.0.3 full client.

Alternatively, you can download ODAC 11.2.0.2(.1), which is a public download, and also contains the required dependencies (no graphical installer though, just a batch file).
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've registered this 11.2.2 dll in the GAC, now I'm getting the exception seen in the latest update.

Comment: This error typically occurs when someone tries to run a 32 bit application with a 64 bit Oracle Client. Is it a 32 bit application? If it is, can you try installing 32 bit ODAC and running with that? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Comment: I have both the 32 bit client and 64 bit client (both 11.2.0.3) installed, as one application requires the 32 bit and others require the 64 bit.  It's strange because I've done this install on another, similarly configured system (nearly identical), and it works successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot does not show the GAC, it should look different (I am not allowed yet to upload pictures as example). Open folder %SystemRoot%\assembly (mostly C:\Windows\assembly) and check content there. Perhaps Oracle.DataAccess was not installed properly.

Kind Regards

Comment: One note: You have to open this folder with standard Windows Explorer. Most other "private" File Explorer do not show the desired content.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, this occur occurred after installing Oracle Client x86 and x64 immediately after each other.  I feel like if I would have rebooted between the two client installs, the issue would not have occurred.

To solve the issue, I uninstalled Oracle Client x64 and reinstalled it using the exact same parameters.  The application then ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Most of issues related to oracle.dataaccess dll caused because of multiple installation. To resolve the issue make sure you uninstalled earlier version properly. It is better to delete oracle home directory , remove GAC references if any and then install desired version.